# How to get size of an area in JavaCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, javacv

In my project I want to get the size from the greatest homogeneous area of a specific color (in my example below it's the blue sky).

My first idea is to convert the orginal image:

[image: original image]

to an binary image, detect the skycolor and create a mask with this area:
[image: mask image]

But how can I get the size and the position of these white pixels? I want a efficient method, which says true, if the picture has a blue sky in the upper 1/3 of the picture.
Any ideas? Should I create a "global mask" (see image 3 in comment) and compare it with the binary picture? Or is there an easier way?

Thank you.

Comment: a new user only can add 2 links :/ here is the mask i think to compare with the second image [see image 3](http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/8231/maskt.jpg)

Comment: do you want to detect blue color or color with biggest square?

Comment: i want the size and the position of the biggest square/area which have blue color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm is the following:

1. Convert input image to [YCbCr color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) which is good to detect blue (and also red) color:
   [image: YCrCb image]
   To convert some image to another color space use [cvtColor](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-cvtcolor).
2. Extract blue channel from it:
   [image: Blue image]
   Use function `extractChannel` to extract needed channel.
3. Detect regions with biggest value *[0-255]* of blue color. I used function [minMaxIdx](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20minMaxIdx%28InputArray%20src,%20double*%20minVal,%20double*%20maxVal,%20int*%20minIdx,%20int*%20maxIdx,%20InputArray%20mask%29) and then just multiplied maximum on **0.8** (this is threshold). You can use more complex methods like histogram analysation.
4. Make a mask of blue color:
   [image: binary]
   For this I used [threshold](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-threshold) function with calculated in step 3 threshold (as parameter).
5. Find all blue contours in mask. In OpenCV it's easy - just use [findContours](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours).
6. And, finally, detect contour with biggest square and find its coordinates (center). To calculate contour with biggest square you can use function [contourArea](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#double%20contourArea%28InputArray%20contour,%20bool%20oriented%29).

Also instead of steps **1-4** you can convert image to [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and using [inRange](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html#cv-inrange) detect blue color.

Here's my c++ impementation:

```
Mat inMat = imread("input.jpg"), blueMat, threshMat;

cvtColor(inMat, blueMat, CV_BGR2YCrCb);//convert to YCrCb color space

extractChannel(blueMat, blueMat, 2);//get blue channel

//find max value of blue color
//or you can use histograms
//or more complex mathod
double blueMax;
minMaxIdx(blueMat, 0, &blueMax);

blueMax *= 0.8;
//make binary mask
threshold(blueMat, threshMat, blueMax, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

//finding all blue contours:
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(blueMat, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

double maxSquare = 0;
vector<Point> maxContour;
//finding contours with biggest square:
for (size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    double square = contourArea(contours[i]);
    if (square > maxSquare)
    {
        maxContour = contours[i];
        maxSquare = square;
    }
}

//output results:
Point center = centerPolygon(maxContour);
cout << "square = " << maxSquare << endl;
cout << "position: x: " << center.x << ", y: " << center.y << endl;
```

Here's `centerPolygon` function:

```
Point centerPolygon(const vector<Point>& points)
{
    int x=0, y=0;

    for (size_t i=0; i<points.size(); i++)
    {
        x += points[i].x;
        y += points[i].y;
    }

    return Point(x/points.size(), y/points.size());
}
```

The output of program is next:

```
square = 263525
position: x: 318, y: 208
```

---

You can convert this code to JavaCV - see [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/ConvertingOpenCV).

Comment: jey, now it works great for me :) But why do you take YCbCr? All the time i thought LAB is the best to detect colors
PS: i can hit +1 only then i have 15 reputations.

Comment: @destiny because YCbCr is the best for blue/red color detection (Cb means channel blue). You can try HSV (or LAB, or some other) - I have already mentioned that in my answer.